# How to tell which option someone picks from a drop-down?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'll save the rant about how poor PayPal's documentation is for another time. Basically I have three buy it now buttons, each one is a drop down menu. What variables should I use to get my IPN handler to differentiate between the three different buttons, and once it figures out which button, to differentiate between the options within each button. (PHP)

The buttons have names like "upgrade1" and "upgrade2" and "upgrade3", and the options look like:

- 1 Month - $9.99
- 2 Months - $18.99
- 3 Months - $25.99

Comment: @robhardgood: Don't rollback my edits, please. And don't write tags in question titles.

Comment: And I'll save the rant about poorly explain explained question for another time, please be a little more specific! ;)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal so I'm not supposed to explain what the question is about, eh? Just leave a really vague title and hope someone clicks on it knowing what it's about? Great plan, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @robhardgood: The tags are in... the tags. No need to duplicate them in the title. Thanks.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: This title is way too vague now, at least you could have made an effort to improve it instead of just removing the tags. If I was familiar with the context I'd do it myself, but I landed here because of the title's ambiguity. Maybe of interest: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/howto-writing-good-titles/10648#10648

Comment: @Wesley: A question is identified by tags and title in combination. It does seems like a poor title, but the solution to that is _not_ to stick a tag in it.

Comment: @Wesley: Also, I don't consider that two-year old, 11-vote answer from a random guy to be authoritative, though there is some good advice on it.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yeah I agree, it's actually pretty iffy but it was the best I had at the moment for OP. The link trail I followed to get there was pretty weak in the answer department.

Answer (score 0):

well if you have your own names of the buttons, you wont get anything in IPN... The important thing  to remember is that PayPal is not using your button names. You have to use pre-defined names from paypal for your buttons. I can see 2 solutions here:
`<select name="item_name">
        <option value="one_month">1 Month - $9.99</option>
        <option value="two_months">2 Months - $18.99</option>
        <option value="three_months">3 Months - $25.99</option>
</select>`

then in your IPN you can find out by
`//which is your item name 'one_month', 'two_months' etc.
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];`

or you could use custom field if you are already using different name for the purchase.
`<select name="custom">
        <option value="one_month">1 Month - $9.99</option>
        <option value="two_months">2 Months - $18.99</option>
        <option value="three_months">3 Months - $25.99</option>
</select>`

which in IPN it it will be as custom variable 
`//which is your item name 'one_month', 'two_months' etc.
$custom = $_POST['custom'];`

there might be more solutions but those one are the easiest and I the most right, in my opinion.

EDIT:
and just so you know, for security reasons you should check if the amount payed is the same as the price of that item.

hope it helps